# boolean not properly stopping mouse event as3

Tags: actionscript-3, boolean, mouseevent

=))  I'm having this simple problem where I want my boolean to become false after the user has found the right combination (so further clicks on the cards wont keep chaging them after the right combination has been found) the code that calls this funcions turns the boolean:podeJogarTrio to true, and the function is working properly. but after I declare it false, I can still keep clicking on the cards and flipping them during the 1 second delay(for animation) that removes the cards! any ideas?? =))

```
function verlaranja()
{
    if(podeJogarTrio == true)
    {
        for(var u:int=0; u < 3; u++)
        {
            var mcLaranja:Laranja = new Laranja();
            mcLaranja.x = larguraTrio + (mcLaranja.width + 5) * (u % 3);
            mcLaranja.y = alturaTrio + (mcLaranja.height + 5) * (Math.floor(u/3));
            mcLaranja.gotoAndStop(u + 1);
            mcLaranja.buttonMode = true;
            mcLaranja.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cliquelaranja);
            mcExplic.addChild(mcLaranja);
            trio.push(mcLaranja);

            function cliquelaranja(e:MouseEvent)
            { 
                e.currentTarget.nextFrame();

                var teste1:int = trio[0].currentFrame;
                var teste2:int = trio[1].currentFrame;
                var teste3:int = trio[2].currentFrame;

                if((teste1 == 3) && (teste2 == 3) && (teste3 == 3))
                {
                    podeJogarTrio = false;    // NOT WORKING PROPERLY!
                    intervalo = setInterval(removeLaranja, intervaloTrio);
                    function removeLaranja()
                    {
                        clearInterval(intervalo);

                        for(var k:int=0; k < 3; k++)
                        {
                            trio[k].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cliquelaranja);
                            mcExplic.removeChild(trio[k]);
                            trace(trio);
                            if(k == 2)
                            {
                                removeTrio();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is very unclear. You have a double inner function and intervals, you should make it more readable.

Comment: its a mini-game within a game, so all variables are stored in one function that only exists while the mini-game is open, I marked "//" where the problem lies.... I dont think I can make this code more organized o.O, what other info you need?

Comment: Nested functions are a bad idea in AS3. You should make a class for your mini-game instead

Comment: You SHOULD make your code more organized cos what I see is simply horrible to read. You basically never need two inner functions, this is not javascript but AS3. (even there a nested function in a nested function is kindof rare, I would say) You should consider making a class for that game, then. Where is podeJogarTrio defined?

Comment: For example what is the interval for? What is intervaloTrio? Is your condition even fired?

Comment: podeJogarTrio is always false. The function that calls this one that I posted makes it true. I'm sorry I'm really a noob.... I'm not sure I know how to make classes... I'm "editing on the timeline".. the entire game is one frame pretty much =(

full game:

$

Comment: interval is for the animation to play. intervaloTrio is 500 (made into a variable coz I'll have to change it after the animation is done, so it fit perfectly) all conditions are fired and the game works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments about avoiding nested functions and setInterval (you should check out the timer class) are all worth considering.

The issue you're having is that you don't remove the event listeners until after the interval has executed, so it stands to reason that the code attached to this listeners will still run when there is a click during that period. There are a few ways you could remedy this, but the easiest is probably to move your conditional to the event listener function:

```
function verlaranja()
{

    for(var u:int=0; u < 3; u++)
    {
        var mcLaranja:Laranja = new Laranja();
        mcLaranja.x = larguraTrio + (mcLaranja.width + 5) * (u % 3);
        mcLaranja.y = alturaTrio + (mcLaranja.height + 5) * (Math.floor(u/3));
        mcLaranja.gotoAndStop(u + 1);
        mcLaranja.buttonMode = true;
        mcLaranja.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cliquelaranja);
        mcExplic.addChild(mcLaranja);
        trio.push(mcLaranja);

        function cliquelaranja(e:MouseEvent)
        {
            // I think you want to check your boolean here
            if (podeJogarTrio) 
            {
                e.currentTarget.nextFrame();

                var teste1:int = trio[0].currentFrame;
                var teste2:int = trio[1].currentFrame;
                var teste3:int = trio[2].currentFrame;

                if((teste1 == 3) && (teste2 == 3) && (teste3 == 3))
                {
                    podeJogarTrio = false;    // NOT WORKING PROPERLY!
                    intervalo = setInterval(removeLaranja, intervaloTrio);
                    function removeLaranja()
                    {
                        clearInterval(intervalo);

                        for(var k:int=0; k < 3; k++)
                        {
                            trio[k].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cliquelaranja);
                            mcExplic.removeChild(trio[k]);
                            trace(trio);
                            if(k == 2)
                            {
                                removeTrio();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! such a silly mistake! I will study more! I got no teacher =( but im trying! =DD